# Correct way to write operator+ using rvalues

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been writing my own String class and I am not sure how to write operator+ correctly considering I could pass rvalues into it.I think I should have the following 3 non-member functions

```
String operator+(String &&lhs, String &&rhs);
String operator+(String& lhs,String&&rhs);
String operator+(String&&lhs,String&rhs);
```

However I am not sure how to implement them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are definitely missing the standard overload `const String &, const String &`. You can find some guidance and examples [in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Comment: Millions before you have written their own string class and have never made one that functioned any better or had less bugs than the standard string class. So, unless this is an academic exercise only, abandon the goal!

Comment: @ChristopherPisz if the writers of `std::string` had that attidute we would have a only the most crappy implementations of it available.

Comment: @nwp I have already writen those I am asking only how I should act when I see rvalue.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz It is for my university I am not allowed to use STL

Comment: @Rostislavstoyanov, That overload should work as is for rvalues.

Comment: The benefit of seeing an rvalue is that you know it is a temporary and can freely screw it up (make sure the destructor still works). For example in the third overload you could do `lhs += rhs; return std::move(lhs);` which steals resources from `lhs` avoiding having to get your own, but since `lhs` immediately dies anyways it's fine.

Comment: @tobi  the writers of string didn't already have a working implementation that has been in use for more than 2 decades and have been thoroughly tested by millions of users.

Comment: @Rostislavstoyanov Well, that's an academic setting. I feel for you. Places that dont use the STL create programmers that I have to work with that don't use the STL. :/

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I doubt that it has been written 2 decades ago and never been improved / changed since then

Comment: @tobi Feel free to IM me if this debate is really that important to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure to define copy and move constructors in your `String` class:

```
class String
{
private:
    char *m_data;
    std::size_t m_length;
    ...

public:
    String();
    String(const String &src);
    String(String &&src);
    ~String();
    ...
};
```

```
String::String() :
    m_data(nullptr),
    m_length(0)
{
}

String(const String &src) :
    m_data(new char[src.m_length+1]),
    m_length(src.m_length)
{
    std::copy_n(src.m_data, m_length, m_data);
    m_data[m_length] = 0;
}

String(String &&src) :
    m_data(nullptr),
    m_length(0)
{
    std::swap(m_data, src.m_data);
    std::swap(m_length, src.m_length);
}

String::~String()
{
    delete[] m_data;
}
```

Then define `operator+` and `operator+=` for the class:

```
class String
{
public:
    ...
    String& operator+=(const String &rhs);
    ...
    friend String operator+(String lhs, const String &rhs)
    {
        lhs += rhs;
        return lhs;
    }
};
```

```
String& String::operator+=(const String &rhs)
{
    String tmp;
    tmp.m_length = m_length + rhs.m_length;
    tmp.m_data = new char[tmp.m_length+1];
    std:copy_n(m_data, m_length, tmp.m_data);
    std:copy_n(rhs.m_data, rhs.m_length, tmp.m_data + m_length);
    tmp.m_data[tmp.m_length] = 0;
    std::swap(m_data, tmp.m_data);
    std::swap(m_length, tmp.m_length);
    return *this;
}
```

By taking a `const String &` as input on the right side, that will handle both lvalue and rvalue inputs.

For `operator+`, the left-hand side is taken by value so the compiler can decide the best constructor to use based on whether the input is an lvalue (copy) or rvalue (move).

Alternatively, you can implement it to take `const String &` on the left side so it still handles lvalues and rvalues, but then you have to implement it similar to how `operator+=` is implemented to avoid the extra allocation of copying `lhs` before concatenating onto it:

```
friend String operator+(const String &lhs, const String &rhs)
{
    /*
    String tmp(lhs);
    tmp += rhs;
    return tmp;
    */

    String tmp;
    tmp.m_length = lhs.m_length + rhs.m_length;
    tmp.m_data = new char[tmp.m_length+1];
    std:copy_n(lhs.m_data, lhs.m_length, tmp.m_data);
    std:copy_n(rhs.m_data, rhs.m_length, tmp.m_data + lhs.m_length);
    tmp.m_data[tmp.m_length] = 0;
    return tmp;
}
```

Either way, you should also define a conversion constructor and `operator+` for `const char *` input as well:

```
class String
{
public:
    ...
    String(const char *src);
    ...
    friend String operator+(const char *lhs, const String &rhs)
    {
        return String(lhs) + rhs;

        /* or:

        std::size_t len = std::strlen(lhs);
        String tmp;
        tmp.m_length = len + rhs.m_length;
        tmp.m_data = new char[tmp.m_length+1];
        std:copy_n(lhs, len, tmp.m_data);
        std:copy_n(rhs.m_data, rhs.m_length, tmp.m_data + len);
        tmp.m_data[tmp.m_length] = 0;
        return tmp;
        */
    }
    ...
};
```

```
String::String(const char *src) :
    m_data(nullptr),
    m_length(std::strlen(src))
{
    m_data = new char[m_length+1];
    std::copy_n(src, m_length, m_data);
    m_data[m_length] = 0;
}
```

This will allow concatenating `String` objects with string literals (`String + "literal"`, `"literal" + String`, `String += "literal"`, etc).

See [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com) for more details.

Comment: There may be value in having versions of these functions that take rvalue references on the left side because then the temporary can be cannibalized for the new value created by `+`. But that's a questionable micro-optimization in the case of `String` (presuming that `String` means a vector of characters and that addition means concatenation).

Comment: Yes, much better than rvalue references on the left side.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do it is like this:

```
class foo
{
...
public:
...
  foo&& operator +(foo const & other) &&;
  foo&& operator +(foo && other) const &;
  foo&& operator +(foo && other) &&;
  foo   operator +(foo const & other) const &;
};
```

Not sure if Microsoft supports this but this is a good way to do this in more recent standards. Try clang if msvc wont let you.

The advantages of doing it this way are that you get very fine levels of control over the method used. These 4 operations can also be defined outside of the class if needed. But you'll always want 4 for the 4 possibilities of r-value/l-value combinations.

Also, you generally want to qualify l-values as const to indicate that they are not modified.

Simply defining a copy/move constructor is not usually an efficient solution to this problem. You will need a good understanding of how rvalue references work to implement this efficiently.

Comment: I might add that the other answer will work but not efficiently. It does not actually handle rvalue references specially but rather treats them as lvalue const references. This will result in inefficient but usable code.